# How to unzip a column in the database using PHP

Tags: php, unzip, kmz

I have a KMZ file stored in MySQL as a blob. KMZ file uses PKZIP compression. How can I unzip the file using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

zip_open() on a temp file or popen /usr/bin/unzip

[this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php#93497) sample shows the basic traversal with zip_open/zip_read

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Any chance that I get a rough example?
Thank you.

Comment: It appears to be a complex way that the string has to be saved first as a file and then unzipped. I thought it was possible to more a more transparent way that hide the complexity somehow.
Thanks again.